# How to calculate size of a pixel for a scanned map?

Tags: raster, scale

A land use map has a scale of 1:150000. The map is scanned at a resolution of 150 DPI. What will be the surface area in m square represented by each pixel in the resulting easter map?

Answer (score 5):

DPI means dots per inch. For your scanned map it is better to use *PPI (pixels per inch)*.

```
150 DPI = 150 PPI = 150 pixels per 1 inch = 150 pixels per 2.54 cm = 150 pixels per 0,0254 m
```

So 1 pixel has the size of `0.0254 m / 150 = 0.00016933 m`.

The scale of our map is 1:150,000. The scale is the ratio of a distance on the map to the corresponding distance on the ground.

So the corresponding distance of one pixel on the ground is `0.00016933 m * 150,000 = 25.4 m`.

One pixel covers an area of `25.4 m * 25.4 m = 645.16 square meters`.